# Laravel 5.3 Eloquent updateOrCreate

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
try {
     \DB::beginTransaction();
      Model::updateOrCreate( ['id' => $id, 'number' => $number],
          ['value' => $request->get('value')]
      );
            \DB::commit();
     } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \DB::rollBack();
            throw new \Exception($e->error());
     }
```

I was working on a task to create a common trait to prevent a record to be updated by multiple users at the same time. And, my method was to put hidden input of $data->updated_at in a blade and then to check it when an update request is sent.  And there are some cases Laravel's updateOrCreate is used to update or create a new record. And, I don't know how to deal with that. Should, I split the methods to create and update or is there any good way to deal with it?

Comment: what part is causing you trouble?

Comment: the problem is that I can't check existing record updated date with updateOrCreate because it just creates a new record if it there is no match in db. There were multiple updateOrCreate methods in the project so I wanted to know if it was possible to keep the method and prevent the existing data to be updated by multiple users at the same time. Sorry, my question was not quite clear I guess

Comment: You should split the update and create into two separate endpoints
Then when doing an update, check if it exists and if it does, update it.

Comment: @Jasurbek thank you, clearer now :). you answered part of this yourself. you can't be using `updateOrCreate` like that if you want to include that field for the reason you mentioned. btw `updateOrCreate` is basically this: `firstOrNew($attributes)->fill($values)->save()`

Comment: @DevinGray it seems it is the only way for what I want to achieve there.

Comment: @lagbox now I understand why it is usually better to separate create and update methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $post = Model::where([['id', $id], ['number', $number]])->first();
    try {
        \DB::beginTransaction();
        if (is_null($post)) {
            Model::create($input);
        } else {
            $post->updateWithExclLock($request->get('updated_at'), $input]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to separate what you are doing.

I was playing around and came up with this for **fun** (haven't tested):

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::macro('createOrUpdateWhen', function ($attributes = [], $values = [], $when = null) {
    $m = $this->firstOrNew($attributes);

    if (is_array($when)) {
        $when = function ($m) use ($when) {
            foreach ($when as $key => $value) {
                if ($m->$key != $value) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    if (! $m->exists || $when($m)) {
        $m->fill($values);
    }

    $m->save();

    return $m;
});

$m = M::createOrUpdateWhen($attributes, $values, function ($m) use ($request) {
    return $m->updated_at == $request->input('updated_at');
});

$m = M::createOrUpdateWhen(
    $attributes, $values, ['updated_at' => $request->input('updated_at')]
);
```

`:-}`

Comment: thanks for your time and code. I have completed the task by separating update and create. 
btw, Is it possible to use macro feature on Laravel 5.3?

Comment: oddly the Eloquent Builder does have a `macro` method in 5.3 but it isn't static like this, so this wont work this way ... this has been adjusted in newer versions ... i do highly suggest upgrading to 5.5 LTS if you can, for numerous other reasons as well